# Mumford Regularity Theorem - Lazarsfeld's proof

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, exact-sequence, sheaf-cohomology

I am studying Lazarsfeld's proof of Mumford's Regularity Theorem. At some point, under the assumption of $\mathcal{F}$ being $m$-regular, he considers the exact sequence

\begin{equation}
    \cdots \to \bigwedge^2 V_{\mathbb{P}} \otimes \mathcal{F}(m-1) \to V_{\mathbb{P}} \otimes \mathcal{F}(m) \to \mathcal{F}(m+1) \to 0
\end{equation}

where $V_{\mathbb{P}} = V \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is an $r$-dimensional projective space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $V$ is an $r+1$-dimensional complex vector space such that $\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{P}(V)$.
He states that by the regularity of $\mathcal{F}$ one concludes the vanishing of

\begin{equation}
H^i(\mathbb{P},\bigwedge^{i+1} V_{\mathbb{P}} \otimes \mathcal{F}(m-i))
\end{equation}

for every $i$. I tried with the definition of cohomology as derived functors, I tried in hoping that $V_{\mathbb{P}}$ could be flasque and then apply Kunneth formula, but it isn't flat or so it seems, and I also tried to look after some vanishing results that could help me here, but nothing seemed to be applying. Why is such statement true?

Comment: The sheaf $\Lambda^{i+1}(V_{\bf P})$ is a direct sum of copies of ${\cal O}_{\bf P}$ so this reduces to showing that $H^i({\bf P},{\cal F}(m-i))=0$. But doesn't this follow from the fact that $\cal F$ is $m$-regular?

Comment: I see, thank you very much! I just didn't notice the fact that $\bigwedge^{i+1} V_{\mathbb{P}}$ was actually free and totally forgot that cohomology and direct sums commute. Again thank you very much!